# Where have I gone wrong with Torricelli's Law?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on Edwards & Penney's Elementary DEs book.  There's an explanation of Torricelli's Law, and I don't understand one of the points.

It says that the velocity of water exiting a hole in a tank is $v=\sqrt{2gy}$ where y is the depth of water at time t, g is gravity.  It says this equation comes from the velocity a drop of water would aquire in freefalling from the surface of the water to the hole.  This is the part I don't understand.

Unless I've made some stupid error, if a drop of water freefalls from a height of y, then it hits the bottom of the tank at $t=\sqrt{\frac{2y}{g}}$ at which point its velocity is $-g\sqrt{\frac{2y}{g}}$, not $\sqrt{2gy}$.

What have I missed?

Comment: It's the same speed, but in a different direction

Comment: I think they're using $\frac{g}{\sqrt{g}}=\sqrt{g}$, and they're taking the downward direction to be positive.

Comment: Also you could use energy conservation so $\frac{mv^2}{2}=mgy \implies v=\sqrt{2gy}$.

Comment: @user84413 Oh yes. I see that now.  (As usual, it's the simple algebra that trips me up :)  Thanks!

Comment: @user116017 Yeah they said something about that, but I didn't get it.  Now I do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Resolution reached in comments: both formulas for velocity agree, up to the sign  which depends on the orientation of the $y$-axis.